# Combinatorial Techniques: Putting two and two together

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

This is a $3$-part question. I got the first two parts, but could not get the third part (which uses the first two parts):

Pick sequence of $8$ coins from sack of $40$ coins, containing $10$ pennies, $10$ nickels, $10$ dimes, $10$ quarters.

a. How many different sequences have exactly $3$ quarters

$$\binom83\cdot3^5$$

b. How many different seqeunces have exactly $3$ quarters and exactly $3$ nickels?

$$\binom83\binom53\cdot2^2$$

c. How many different sequences have exactly $3$ quarters or exactly $3$ nickels?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_inclusion_exclusion

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_1$ be the set of sequences with exactly $3$ quarters and $S_2$ the set of sequences with exactly $3$ nickels. Then $S_1\cup S_2$ is the set of sequences with exactly $3$ quarters or exactly $3$ nickels, and $S_1\cap S_2$ is the set of sequences with exactly $3$ quarters **and** exactly $3$ nickels.

You want $|S_1\cup S_2|$. You already know that

$$|S_1|=|S_2|=\binom83\cdot3^5\;,$$

so you could start with $|S_1|+|S_2|=2\binom83\cdot3^5$ as a first approximation to $|S_1\cup S_2|$. However, every sequence in $S_1\cap S_2$ is counted **twice** in that figure, so it’s an overestimate. What must you subtract in order to correct that overcounting?

If you get completely stuck, [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_inclusion_exclusion) tells you what to do right at the beginning, but you should try to work it out yourself. After you’ve done that, though, the article is well worth reading.